# Frontend file upload works, but I get error "Constant ABSPATH already defined"

Tags: uploads, wp-load.php

I am uploading files from the frontend. It works perfectly, yet I am getting the error:

> Constant ABSPATH already defined

This is at the top of my file upload script:

```
require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wp-load.php");
// require two files that are included in the wp-admin but not on the front end.  These give you access to some special functions below.
require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wp-admin/includes/file.php");
require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wp-admin/includes/image.php");
```

`wp-load.php` is not being loaded anywhere else manually, only here. The file upload works as expected, the only issue is the Notice that PHP is spitting out.

If I use `require_once` then I get more errors (though it does still upload as expected?).

Any ideas?

**Edit: more information**

A search through /wp-content/* shows the term wp-load only once - that is from the above code.

Maybe there is a way to autoload wp-load.php without including the phrase wp-load??

The code requiring wp-load is within a theme template (not a plugin). Specifically, within a page-template that allows a custom post to be added/edited from the frontend.

If I remove the line that requires wp-load.php, then the image upload still works. However, I get the following errors (sensitive info in directory structure has been omitted):

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /<Path to file>/file_upload.php on line 25

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /<Path to file>/file_upload.php on line 26

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /<Path to file>/file_upload.php on line 27

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /<Path to file>/file_upload.php on line 28

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /<Path to file>/file_upload.php on line 29

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /<Path to file>/file_upload.php on line 25

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /<Path to file>/file_upload.php on line 26

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /<Path to file>/file_upload.php on line 27

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /<Path to file>/file_upload.php on line 28

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /<Path to file>/file_upload.php on line 29

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /<Path to file>/file_upload.php on line 25

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /<Path to file>/file_upload.php on line 26

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /<Path to file>/file_upload.php on line 27

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /<Path to file>/file_upload.php on line 28

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /<Path to file>/file_upload.php on line 29

Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in /<Path to file>/file_upload.php on line 25

Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in /<Path to file>/file_upload.php on line 26

Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in /<Path to file>/file_upload.php on line 27

Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in /<Path to file>/file_upload.php on line 28

Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in /<Path to file>/file_upload.php on line 29

Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in /<Path to file>/file_upload.php on line 25

Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in /<Path to file>/file_upload.php on line 26

Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in /<Path to file>/file_upload.php on line 27

Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in /<Path to file>/file_upload.php on line 28

Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in /<Path to file>/file_upload.php on line 29
```

This error is referencing the $file_array array from here:

```
if ($count_files > 0) {
    foreach ( range( 0, $count_files ) as $i ) {

        // create an array of the $_FILES for each file
        $file_array = array(
            'name'      => urlencode($_FILES['logo']['name'][$i]),
            'type'      => $_FILES['logo']['type'][$i],
            'tmp_name'  => $_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'][$i],
            'error'     => $_FILES['logo']['error'][$i],
            'size'      => $_FILES['logo']['size'][$i],
        );

        if ( !empty( $file_array['name'] ) ) {

            $uploaded_file = wp_handle_upload( $file_array, $upload_overrides );

            $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $uploaded_file['file'] ), null );   

            $attachment = array(
                'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
                'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $uploaded_file['file'] ) ),
                'post_content' => 'logo',
                'post_author' => $logged_in_user,
                'post_status' => 'inherit',
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'post_parent' => $_POST['post_id'],
                'guid' => $uploads['baseurl'] . '/' . date( 'Y/m' ) . '/' . $file_array['name'],
                'post_date' => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ),
                'post_date_gmt' => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' )
            );


            $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, '/' . date( 'Y/m' ) . '/' . $file_array['name'], $_POST['post_id'] );

            $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $uploaded_file['file'] );

            wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id,  $attach_data );

            set_post_thumbnail( $_POST['post_id'], $attach_id );

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Then the file is being loaded automatically for some reason. Please add more detail to this question, and for the record, explicitly `require`ing files is nearly always "doing it wrong".

Comment: Thanks for responding, @s_ha_dum. I have added some more information to the question - if there is anything else I should add please let me know. What would the correct alternative to require-ing be?

Comment: "What would the correct alternative to require-ing be?" -- the [AJAX API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) solves a _lot_ of these kinds of issues, and despite the name the request doesn't actually have to be initiated by Javascript. A request is a request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The code requiring wp-load is within a theme template (not a plugin).
>   Specifically, within a page-template that allows a custom post to be
>   added/edited from the frontend.

A page template should not require any explicit loading of the WordPress Core. The template itself wouldn't load if WordPress were not already loaded.

Your other errors are because there are apparently no `$_FILES['logo']['type'][1]`, `$_FILES['logo']['type'][2]`, `$_FILES['logo']['type'][3]`, or `$_FILES['logo']['type'][4]`. You need to `var_dump($_FILES);` and see exactly what you are dealing with, but that is a pure PHP problem and would off-topic here.

Comment: Perfect. After some digging around I changed the loop and now it's working fine. Thanks a lot for your time and effort!